# Compile Script file in SQL Developer (ORACLE)

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, sql-scripts

I am executing a script file (c:\sqlfiles\Test.sql) from SQL Developer. File contains below statements

```
@@test1.sql;
@@test2.sql;
@@test3.sql;
```

All these sql files contains function or procedures.

But the problem is while running the command @c:\sqlfiles\Test.sql I am getting below ERROR . How can i clear it?

```
Error starting at line 1 in command:
ï»¿
Error report:
Unknown Command
FUNCTION test1 compiled
FUNCTION test2 compiled
FUNCTION test3 compiled
```

Comment: This sounds as if your SQL scripts are saved as UTF with a BOM header (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). SQL*Plus does not support this, and the error message sounds as if SQL Developer also doesn't. Try saving the files without a BOM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to save your file to ANSI (change their encoding) then try. or utf8 without BOM